# Should you still exercise when sick?

Tags: exercise, recovery, illness

Should one continue to exercise even when you are sick?

I know it may depend on the sickness, so I am specifically asking about minor things like a cold or fever?

Are there chronic sicknesses where you should still regularly exercise?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should you run with a cold?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/248/should-you-run-with-a-cold)

Comment: I wouldn't close this as duplicate.  The other question was specific to running.  This involves exercise in general.  Would  you close the question:  Can I go for a walk when sick? or Can I lift weights when sick?  If you close one, close the running one and merge the answers here, then you can justify closing all the more specific instances of this question.

Comment: My coach said any symptoms below the neck stops training.

Answer (score 14):

No, you should not exercise with with temporary illness such as a chest cold, flu, or fever. A runny nose or sore throat shouldn't prevent your exercise routine though. Once you have an infection or illness that effects your cardiovascular or digestive system, you should sit it out and let your body have the time needed to heal itself.

People with chronic ailments such as asthma, heart disease, and anything more serious needs to talk to their doctor before even thinking the word exercise. Some people can, some people can't even with the same symptoms. Your doctor will know best.

Comment: Maybe you should elaborate on the difference between flu vs runny nose...

Comment: To me, a runny nose is just one symptom (and the individual doesn't necessarily have an illness as it could just be allergies) whereas the flu can have fever, fatigue, aches, congestion, sneezing, coughing, and other symptoms.